# cycle accurate model pointer and array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am currently developing a cycle accurate model for RISC processor using pipelining. I wrote the code for pipe-lining method using some code samples from my lecturer, but it doesn't work. I am a bit confused with the following function:

```
void rf (int RS1, int RS2, int RD, dramcmdT cmd1, dramcmdT cmd2, dramcmdT cmd3, int din, int *dout1, int *dout2) 
{
    static int array[32];

    if (cmd1 == RD) 
        *dout1 = array[RS1];
    if (cmd2 == RD) 
        *dout2 = array[RS2];
    if (cmd3 == WR) 
        array[RD] = din;
}
```

RS1, RS2, RD are some integer values I send, cmd1 and cmd2 are always RD and cmd3 is always WR. So basically all if statements should be executed, but they do not. I always get zeros in dout1 and dout2. I was asking my lecturer whether *dout1 = array[RS1] is a correct notation and he says it is correct, but I don't understand what does it do and why I get zeros in dout1 and dout2? Is anyone familiar with this notation?

Answer (score 1):

How do you set the values in `array`? The only value that it's possible to write is `array[RD]`. Based on your description, `RD` is a constant. So, you can only ever initialize one element of the array.

Alternatively, `RD` is not a constant, in which case what are `cmd1 == RD` and `cmd2 == RD` about?

This duplicate use of `RD` as a command and as an array index is very unusual and confusing.

Oh, BTW, `*dout1 = array[RS1]` is correct notation. That's not the problem.

Comment: RD plays a role of a destination register (address) and it is not constant. RD changes depending on commands I send. It eventually initializes many elements in the array. so array[RD] = din means put input data into a specific location in array (address).

cmd1 == RD is different.. You are right. it is a bit ambiguous, but I created typedef enum {RD, WR, NOP} dramcmdT; cmd1 is of type dramcmdT. 

But you are right i will change int RD to rd.. But can you explain to me what *dout1 = array[RS1] means? it just takes an element from array and puts in dout?

Comment: Yes, `dout` is a pointer to an `int`; `dout = x` puts `x` in the pointer; `*dout = x` puts `x` in the `int` that the pointer points to.